# Custom order of test database migrations

Tags: django, database, testing, pytest-django

I'm running django tests on a large application. They require a test database, so I need to create a test database before running tests. But the problem is - because of some dependency problems the migration must be run in the following order: **migrate app2, migrate app1, migrate**. I know that I'm doing it wrong but I have no will and time to fix hundreds of migrations.

The question is:
Is there any way to create database for tests separately from running them to use it later via *--keep-db* option? Because app database creation needs special command order described above I can't just run "test" command to prepare database and run tests.

Comment: Your question doesn't match your actual description, what are you actually asking about?

Comment: Sorry, title from other question, did not noticed.

Comment: Hi some time has passed since you asked this. I am stuck at exactly the same problem. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Nope, I left this project - seems like you cant avoid fixing technical debt here )